# C++, OpenGL: High level library for animating / transitioning objects

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, transition

I've been programming in Javascript for a while and I find it very productive with timeless of coding. I'm back for now in C++ again and doing some OpenGL. I was thinking if there are existing libraries for C++ to handle smooth animations and transition of displayed objects, hopefully like there in Javascript?

Or if there aren't any, can you show some code trick to do it quickly?

I'm a bit hurry now and I want this to be done ASAP.
Google is unfriendly to me, I can't find any :(

Comment: Can you take on any big dependencies? For example, the Qt project has QML which is a declarative language with scripting in JavaScript which is built upon OpenGL and can tie into native C++ code easily. It has tons of support for the kind of animations you mention. Of course if you aren't willing to take on a rather big dependency, it won't help you.

Comment: @ksimons I was just about to mention QML, you beat me to the punch. :)